# Projection of a Great Circle on another

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-geometry, geodesy

Consider a great circle between $[lat_1, lon_1]$ and $[ lat_2, lon_2]$, on a perfectly spherical earth.

Consider a second one : between  $[lat_1, lon_1 +b]$ and $[ lat_2, lon_2+b]$. For a very small constant $b$, if the great circles themselves are small, they can be considered parallel to each other.

Both are segments of circles and thus does not go completely around the world. I want to project one great circle segment upon the other to find out if these segments "overlap" each other.

Overlap :

[image]

Overlap happens in between the two green dotted lines. If I move the second great circle by $-b$, then the "overlap" is the common sub-segment of both segments of great circles.

Edit after @michaelseifert 's comment :

The green lines should be normals dropped from one segment to another. However, I also do not have a proper algorithm / formula to do that. After the projection on the cylinder, I was painstakingly evaluating each endpoint to drop these normals. Even tho, it is done on a computer, I think there should be better ways of doing it.

Edit 2 :

Once I project the Great Circles on a cylinder (see below in attempt to solution), the arcs of latitude and longitude become straight lines. For very short lengths of great circle segments, I can approximate them as straight lines. Then I can drop normals.

The outcome will be the same, if I could draw the shortest cross track great circle segments between the two given great circle segments defined by $[lat_1, lon_1]$ , $[ lat_2, lon_2]$, and  $[lat_1, lon_1 +b]$ , $[ lat_2, lon_2+b]$ - from the points that delimit the "overlapping". I realize that overlapping and the normals are defined w.r.t. each other, and that bad. But the plan is to extract parallel GPS tracks, and trim them if one exceeds a certain length beyond overlapping.

**Attempt to solution**

I tried to convert the polar coordinates to cartesian, butthey are in 3D.

In order to reduce them to 2D i am projecting them on a cylinder like mercator projection and unwrapping it.

**Problem with this approach**

At higher latitudes the surface of the cylinder is very far away from the surface of the sphere leading to large errors.

**Question**

How can I project one great circle segment on another without first having to project them on a cylinder or other surface?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "overlap"?  Is that the same thing as "intersect"?  If so, I suspect that there will be a simpler geometric argument that doesn't involve projections.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert edited question to indicate overlap.

Comment: How are the dotted green lines determined?  Are they lines of latitude?  Something else?  (If they're lines of latitude, then the question is trivial, because the two great-circle arcs span exactly the same range of latitude;  so I assume they're something else.)

Comment: those should be normals dropped from one segment to another. However, I also do not have a proper algorithm / formula to do that. After the projection, I was painstakingly evaluating each endpoint to drop these normals.

Comment: In general, a great circle that is normal to one of the arcs will not necessarily intersect the other arc at a 90° angle.  (Consider the case of where both arcs are segments of lines of longitude to see this.) So you may need to be more specific about how you're constructing your normals.

Comment: After I project them on the cylinder, both lat and lon arcs become straight lines. For very short lengths of great circles, I can approximate them as straight lines. Then I can drop normals. The outcome will be the same, if I could draw the shortest cross track great circles between the two arcs, where they "overlap". I realize that overlapping and the normals are defined w.r.t. each other, and that bad. But the plan is to extract parallel GPS tracks, and trim them if one exceeds a certain length beyond overlapping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118696/discussion-between-michael-seifert-and-sean).

Answer (score 1):

*Comment*... trying to understand your question..i.e,

By their definition, two geodesics/great circles can never be parallel. They intersect at *two* points.

For parallels at least one should be a *small circle.*

Every small circle is non-geodesic, that is, the normal *to the surface* at a given point P and *normal to the small circle* at P  makes the same angle between them.

I.e., the $\phi=5^{\circ}$ parallel circle on a sphere has this angle constant  *all along* the small circle length.

Two given points and sphere center determine a great circle. With respect to a great circle can define the *relative latitude* for a small parallel circle $\phi$ thus:

For a great circle Clairaut circle radius $  is a constant (blue). For a small circle it varies as shown (red). Using Liouville theorem of geodesic curvature we can establish that

$$\tan \phi= \dfrac{d (r \sin \psi)}{dz}=\dfrac{d (r_{Clairaut})}{dz}; $$
It vanishes for a great circle but is a constant for small circle, $\psi$ being angle between meridian and the small circle.

[image: Relative Latitude]

Comment: true. But for short lengths, i can approximate the small circle with the great circle.  This enables me to use thr distance formulae.

Comment: I recommend using " parallel small circle " to avoid any conceptual errors..

Comment: Can you point me to any resources showing how to compute distances along them, how to uniquely define such a small circle using just two pair of coordinates, etc. Please?

Comment: You need *three* inputs, apart from the given two points, the relative latitude of the parallel small circle, (which goes to zero in case of great circle) along the third side.

Comment: If all three arcs are geodesics then path/distance is solved by spherical sine,cosine laws

Comment: what is "relative altitude"? How to calculate it?

Comment: Explaining it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118762/discussion-between-sean-and-narasimham).

Comment: Please see the sketch, glad to answer questions.